# Understanding a proof of a corollary in chapter 2 about invertibility of a p-adic integer (Jean-Pierre Serre)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

In a proof of a corollary in chapter 2, there is a step I don't understand.

> **Corollary 2:** Suppose $p \neq 2$. Let $f(X) = \sum_j a_{ij}X_iX_j$ with $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ be a quadratic form with coefficients in
>   $\mathbb{Z}_p$ whose discriminant $\det (a_{ij})$ is invertible. Let
>   $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Every primitive solution of the equation $f(x) \equiv a \mod p$ lifts to a solution with coefficients in
>   $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
>
> **Proof:** (...), it suffices to show that $x$ does not annihilate all the partial derivatives of $f$ modulo $p$. Now $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_i} = 2 \sum_j a_{ij} X_j$; since $\det (a_{ij}) \not\equiv 0 \mod p$ and $x$ is primitive, one of these partial
>   deriviatives is $\not\equiv 0 \mod p$.

If I'm not mistaken, then one step I need to conclude: If $\det(a_{ij}) \not\equiv 0 \mod p$, then $a_{ij} \not\equiv 0 \mod p$.
However, I failed to show that.
I tried the following:

$\det(a_{ij}) = 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \ldots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
(\ldots, a_{11}^{(k)}, \ldots, a_{11}^{(1)}) & \ldots & (\ldots, a_{1n}^{(k)}, \ldots, a_{1n}^{(1)}) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
(\ldots, a_{n1}^{(k)}, \ldots, a_{11}^{(1)}) & \ldots & (\ldots, a_{nn}^{(k)}, \ldots, a_{nn}^{(1)})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\left( 
\ldots, \det
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}^{(k)} & \ldots & a_{1n}^{(k)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1}^{(k)} & \ldots & a_{nn}^{(k)}
\end{pmatrix},
\ldots,
\det \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}^{(1)} & \ldots & a_{1n}^{(1)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1}^{(1)} & \ldots & a_{nn}^{(1)}
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
$

Therefore, if $\det(a_{ij}) \not\equiv 0 \mod p$, then each component has to fulfill $\not\equiv 0 \mod p$.

Now, I could use Leibniz's formula [1] to calculate each determinant, but I don't see from here, why $a_{ij}^{(k)}$ has to be $\not\equiv 0 \mod p$.

Then I looked at the special case $n=2$. We have

$\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}^{(k)} & a_{12}^{(k)} \\
a_{21}^{(k)} & a_{22}^{(k)}
\end{pmatrix} =
a_{11}^{(k)}a_{22}^{(k)} - a_{21}^{(k)}a_{12}^{(k)} \not\equiv 0 \mod p$.

But for me this doesn't necessarily mean, that $a_{11}^{(k)} \not\equiv 0 \mod p$ and $a_{12}^{(k)} \not\equiv 0 \mod p$ and $a_{22}^{(k)} \not\equiv 0 \mod p$.

Did I miss something?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants

Comment: It would help if you could distinguish between $a_{ij}$ the matrix and $a_{ij}$ the entry of the matrix. Additionally, the identity matrix has determinant $1$, but has $0s$, which aren't invertible, so your question is a little unclear.

Comment: @TokenToucan: Ok, I edited the title. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point is that, if $M = (a_{ij})$ and $\det M\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $M$ has an inverse: there is some $N$ with $MN\equiv NM\equiv I \pmod{p}$.

Suppose $x$ is primitive and nonzero, and we have $\sum_{j} a_{ij} x_j \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for all $i$.  Then $Mx \equiv 0\pmod{p}$.  But multiplying on the left by $N$ gives us $x\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, which is impossible.

Comment: Then the determinant has to be divisible by $p$. But how do I know, that $a_{ij} \not\equiv 0 \mod p$ for the right $i$ and $j$?

Comment: @Kimmel Okay, I think I understand what you're asking.  See my updated answer: we don't need any particular coefficients to be nonzero, what we need is for the kernel to be trivial.

Comment: Neat solution. Sorry, that my question was somewhat unclear.